# To Disable Ctrl + Alt + Arrowkeys using registry or any script

Tags: windows

CTRL/ALT/arrows....flipping my screen sideways and upways.

I have tried below registry setting but it doesn't work

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AutoRotation]
"Enable"=dword:00000000

Is there anyway it can be disabled? Or if we get the script to disable using AutoHotkey is also good.

I don't have option to disable using Intel Grahics page (Right-click on your desktop background and select Graphics Options > Hot Keys > Disable). Hot Keys option is not available. I have tried to disable it through group policy but it is not working.

Below are the system details:
Edition Windows 10 IoT Enterprise LTSC
Version 21H2
OS build 19044.3448

Answer (score 0):

Those are handled by your Intel GPU driver.

- Open the "Intel Graphics Command Center" (there might be a special item in the desktop's right-click menu), then go *somewhere* and disable the "Hotkeys" option. (My version has it under "System", but it no longer has the arrow hotkeys anyway; I think the layout was different in the older pre-UWP app.)
- If you have a 'tray' icon for Intel Graphics, right-click it and the menu (if I remember correctly) also had an option to disable the hotkeys.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. The above Intel Graphics option to disable 'Hot keys' doesn't exists. So the above solution won't work. I have tried to disable Hot key from Group policy but that option also not working.

Comment: It exists somewhere, in all versions I've seen; you _probably_ have it in the right-click menu at least.